# Can we define classes at runtime using an object of keyed functions?

Tags: javascript, class, coffeescript

I'm trying to create a mock helper that can mock a class and return specific values for specific method names:

```
  methods_values =
    a : 1
    b : 2
    c : 3
  methods = {}
  for method, value of methods_values
    methods[method] = ->
      value
  console.log methods
  // Outputs "{ a: [Function], b: [Function], c: [Function] }"

  class MockClass
    methods
  mock_instance = new MockClass()
  console.log mock_instance
  // Outputs "{}"

  for method, value of methods_values
    console.log method
    // Outputs "a"

    console.log mock_instance[method]()
    // Gives error "TypeError: Object #<MockClass> has no method 'a'"
```

I can see why this doesn't work from the compiled code, however I'm not able to identify a way forward. Is this even possible via coffeescript or does the way it is compiled prevent me from gaining the right scope?

**SOLUTION**: Thanks to @Leonid Beschastny's answer, the following code works:

```
  methods_values =
    a : 1
    b : 2
    c : 3
  mock_methods = (proto, _methods_values) ->
    for method, value of _methods_values
      do (_value = value) ->
        proto[method] = -> _value
    return
  class MockClass
    mock_methods @::, methods_values

  mock_instance = new MockClass()
  for method, value of methods_values
    console.log method
    console.log mock_instance[method]()
```

Outputs:

```
a
1
b
2
c
3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so you should mix all your `methods` into `MockClass.prototype`. Here is an example of doing it:

```
mixin = (proto, methods) ->
  for name, fn of methods
    proto[name] = fn
  return

class MockClass
  mixin @::, methods
```

or in your case

```
mock_methods = (proto, methods_values) ->
  for method, value of methods_values
    do (value) -> proto[method] = -> value
  return

class MockClass
  mock_methods @::, methods_values
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Although I had to restrict the scope for the `proto[method] = -> value`

Comment: @DanH Whoops, my fault. Forgot to add a closure. Fixed.